# Does this Latin phrase convey a meaning?

Tags: meaning

I'd like to utilize *Homines Ludente, Homines Impudente* as an epigraph.  But I'm not sure whether it conveys a meaning.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Without context, its difficult to say. What I see is "Men with (someone/something) playing, Men with shameless (something)." It would make sense at a party, maybe, where the man playing is some sort of wacky entertainer.

Comment: Specifically "with" in the sense of "by using", not "accompanied by".

Comment: I suggest rephrasing the question:  As the current comments suggest, the phrase means *something*, but almost certainly not what you (or someone else) intended. You could get a fuller answer if you gave some more context.

Comment: without a context I could guess the extended meaning as 'To learn, one must be shameless, so that he can create a playground on the subject, try and fail'. Many people can't learn a language because they have the shame to talk in the wrong way for example, meanwhile shameless people do horrible talks but learn the correct way in time

Answer (score 6):

Literally, this means **people doing something by using the playing thing, people doing something by using the shameless thing**. So yes, it does convey a meaning, but I'm guessing it's not the meaning you're aiming for.

Comment: If I were bold enough, I'd summarise this answer to the question as "no" (which I agree with).